# Cors with SignalR - solving the "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, signalr

I am working with Angular 2 and ASP.NET Core with SignalR.

I have the error shown below:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://localhost:55916/signalr//signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22event%22%7D%5D&_=1486394845411.
> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
> must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
> access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

There is my app config:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["data:secretKey"]));

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
                        

            app.UseCors(config =>
                 config.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());

            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseSignalR("/signalr");

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I have also Angular 2 SignalR service witch

```
constructor(){
 //setups...

  this.connection = $.hubConnection(this.baseUrl + 'signalr/');
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);

    this.registerOnServerEvents();

    this.startConnection();
}
```

regiestering server events:

```
 private registerOnServerEvents(): void {
        this.proxy.on('FoodAdded', (data: any) => {
            debugger;
            this.foodchanged.emit(data);
        });

        this.proxy.on('FoodDeleted', (data: any) => {
            debugger;
            this.foodchanged.emit('this could be data');
        });

        this.proxy.on('FoodUpdated', (data: any) => {
            debugger;
            this.foodchanged.emit('this could be data');
        });

        this.proxy.on('SendMessage', (data: ChatMessage) => {
            debugger;
            console.log('received in SignalRService: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            this.messageReceived.emit(data);
        });

        this.proxy.on('newCpuValue', (data: number) => {
            debugger;
            this.newCpuValue.emit(data);
        });
    }
```

The error begins at the beginning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out. While setting connection in client side I had to add

> withCredentials

property to false

So the code looks like:

```
private startConnection(): void {
    this.connection.start({ withCredentials: false }).done((data: any) => {
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);
        this.connectionExists = true;
    }).fail((error: any) => this.connectionEstablished.emit(false));
}
```

Comment: This was a huge source of pain and sorely missed in the MS docs. Have you found anywhere Microsoft outlines all of the overloads for connection.start()? In so many of the examples they just show allowing all "*" origins for CORS and leave it at that. This isn't an angular specific issue, but comes up with any use of the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, this won't build. See @no1spirite's answer below. The key is to add `.AllowCredentials()` in your .NET startup configuration.

Comment: In TypeScript you should do: `new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("http://localhost:7071/api", {withCredentials: false})
        .build();`

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me

```
    app.UseCors(config => config.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
```

Got to add the AllowCredentials option

Comment: This combination produces for me: `The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-allowed-origins
```Specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods.```

Answer (score 6):

In .Net 7 if you want to use **AllowAnyOrigin** you need to set the **withCredentials** property to be false in javascript.

So, the next code will work in .Net 7.

.Net part:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddSignalR(o =>
{
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors();

app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapHub<MessageHub>("/messageHub");
```

JS part to instantiate a connection:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("URL_TO_SERVER/messageHub", { withCredentials: false })
.build();
```

So, the trick is to pass the options **{ withCredentials: false }** to the **withUrl** method.

Answer (score 4):

As long as credentials security is used in your application you should specify domain(s) from which CORS requests may come to your server:

```
app.UseCors(config => config.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080"));
```

Value of credentials security is greatly reduced if you're allowing CORS requests from any domain in the world. That is what error message telling us.

Comment: do you know how to do this with wildcard support